# I want community users to see only contacts related to the Account , but i want the users to see all the term records (irrespective of the Account)

Tags: community, lightning-experience, sharing, owd

Scenario:

There are three objects Account, Contact and Term(this object has master detail relationship with Account and is also a part of a managed package)

Account OWD:Private
Contact OWD: Controlled by Parent
Term OWD : controlled by Parent

Use Case: I want community users to see only contacts related to the Account , but i want the users to see all the term records (irrespective of the Account)

What all i tried: 1.I tried changing the OWD of the term(I cannot due to master detail with Account)
2. I tried deleting the master detail relationship on the Term Object , i could not because the field belongs to a managed package.

Now how do i tackle this? How can i let the community users see all the terms and only contacts related to that Account?

PLEASE HELP

Comment: What community license are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since `TERM` has a master detail relationship with Account, the visibility will depend on the parent, you won't be to give access to all details records i.e. `TERM` records without exposing the `Accounts` (View All on `Term` or sharing rules if you have Community Plus license)

The only option would be create a page + controller in without sharing mode and the record UI page as well but the access will be limited to this page only (No global search or standard list views)